# Creating new columns given if an event happen in a window of time (future or past)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
ID    date           e_1   
 1    2016-02-01     False 
      2016-02-02     False 
      2016-02-03     True  
      2016-02-04     False
      2016-02-05     False
      2016-02-06     False
      2016-02-07     False
      2016-02-08     False
      2016-02-09     False
      2016-02-10     False  
 2    2016-02-01     False  
      2016-02-02     True    
      2016-02-03     True    
      2016-02-04     False  
          ...         ...
```

I want to add several columns that encode the following: *Does the `e_1` is `True` in the following `1d`, `2d`, `3d`, `4d`, `5d`, `1 month`... etc?*

I will like to specify the delta in time in a list. The name of the columns will be the `e1_XX` where `XX` is the delta (i.e. `1d`, etc)

I tried with `shift` but that just moves the values. Also tried with `rolling` (it seems more suitable for this task):

```
df.groupby('ID').rolling(3).agg(???)
```

But I don' t know how to pass the condition (I though in something like `np.any`), but I am stuck

Answer (score 4):

You can using `groupby` with `rolling` `apply`

```
df.groupby('ID').e_1.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[::-1].rolling(window=3,min_periods=1).apply(any).iloc[::-1].astype(bool))
Out[51]: 
ID  date      
1   2016-02-01     True
    2016-02-02     True
    2016-02-03     True
    2016-02-04    False
    2016-02-05    False
    2016-02-06    False
    2016-02-07    False
    2016-02-08    False
    2016-02-09    False
    2016-02-10    False
2   2016-02-01     True
    2016-02-02     True
    2016-02-03     True
    2016-02-04    False
Name: e_1, dtype: bool
```

EDIT : `groupby` the index ID , then we have series of e_1 for each ID , and check the [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) for rolling , it can accept offset which means when your index is datetime ,it can using `offset`(3d means 3 days) to determine the window size

```
df.groupby('ID').e_1.apply(lambda x : x.reset_index(level=0,drop=True).rolling('3d').apply(any))
```

Update , we need create the another column to help , this logic equal to [::-1], but just when you are using time index : ***index must be monotonic***

```
df['New']=pd.to_datetime('today')+(pd.to_datetime('today')-df.index.get_level_values(1))
df=df.sort_index(level=0).sort_values('New')
df['New']=df.groupby('ID',sort=False).apply(lambda x : x.reset_index(drop=True).set_index('New')['e_1'].rolling('3d',min_periods=1).apply(any)).sort_index(level=1).values.astype(bool)
df.sort_index()
Out[278]: 
                 e_1    New
ID date                    
1  2016-02-01  False   True
   2016-02-02  False   True
   2016-02-03   True   True
   2016-02-04  False  False
   2016-02-05  False  False
   2016-02-06  False  False
   2016-02-07  False  False
   2016-02-08  False  False
   2016-02-09  False  False
   2016-02-10  False  False
2  2016-02-01  False   True
   2016-02-02   True   True
   2016-02-03   True   True
   2016-02-04  False  False
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you answer the part in the question related  to add several columns? Also, Could you explain your approach?

Comment: Your first approach works, but the second one is incorrect, I am getting 
     `ID  date      
1   2016-02-01    1.0
    2016-02-02    1.0
    2016-02-03    1.0
    2016-02-04    0.0
    2016-02-05    0.0
    2016-02-06    0.0
    2016-02-07    0.0
    2016-02-08    0.0
    2016-02-09    0.0
    2016-02-10    0.0
2   2016-02-01    1.0
    2016-02-02    1.0
    2016-02-03    1.0
    2016-02-04    0.0` (i.e. is going backwards, kind of)

Answer (score 2):

check the following code and see if it works:

```
# make sure date is in valid Pandas datetime format
mydf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(mydf['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# use date as index to make it easier in date manipulations
mydf.set_index('date', inplace=True)

def flag_visits(grps, d, d_name):
    """Loop through each group and extend the index to 'd' more days from
       df_grp.index.max(). fill the NaN values with *False*
       this is needed to retrieve the forward rolling stats when running shift(1-d)
    """
    for id, df_grp in grps:
        # create the new index to cover all days required in calculation
        idx = pd.date_range(
              start = df_grp.index.min()
            , end   = df_grp.index.max() + pd.DateOffset(days=d)
            , freq  = 'D'
        )

        # set up the new column 'd_name' for the current group
        mydf.loc[mydf.ID == id, 'e1_'+d_name] = (df_grp.reindex(idx, fill_value=False)
                                                       .e_1.rolling(str(d)+'d', min_periods=0)
                                                       .sum().gt(0)
                                                       .shift(1-d)
        )

# if you know the dates are continue without gap, then you might also reverse the dates, do the regular backward rolling(), and then flip it back. However, you can not do the rolling() by the number of day, only by the number of records. 
def flag_visits_1(grps, d, d_name):
    for id, df_grp in grps:
        mydf.loc[mydf.ID == id, 'e1_'+d_name] = (df_grp.sort_index(ascending=False)
                                                       .e_1.rolling(d, min_periods=0)
                                                       .sum().gt(0).sort_index()
        )



# d is the actual number of days used in Series.rolling(), d_name used in the column name"""
for d, d_name in [ (2, '1d') , (3, '2d'), (7, '6d'), (30, '1m') ]:
    mydf.groupby('ID').pipe(flag_visits, d, d_name)

# drop date from the index 
mydf.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(mydf)
```

**Note:**

- If the `next 1 day` does not include today, thus when d_name == '1d', d == 1, then you can adjust the `shift(1-d)` to `shift(-d)`
- date field must be unique for each ID, or you will not be able to set_index()